# How to create a manifest file for TLBs which are used for remote COM objects only?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, com, regfreecom

My Delphi application `Client.exe` needs a couple of `.tlb` files to work. These files define server interfaces. The corresponding object instances are created with `System.Win.ComObj.CreateRemoteComObject`.

**What is the problem?**

For now the `.tlb` files are registered globally during the installation using `regtlibv12.exe` and are unregistered on uninstalling the software. This makes it impossible to install and uninstall multiple instances of the same software since it can break the TLB registrations.

**Attempt to solve it with [Registration Free COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)**

The idea is to use the `.tlb` files without registration but with a `.manifest` file. 
I know how to use a [customized Windows application manifest file with Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Customizing_the_Windows_Application_Manifest_File). But I don't know how to extract the information from the `.tlb` files and create the correct `.manifest` file.

I have found [Mt.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa375649) which can be used to generate `.manifest` files but it doesn't help me because

- it's asking for a corresponding DLL file when the `-tlb` parameter is set but there are no `.dll` files shipped with the application since the COM objects are created on remote machines
- it doesn't accept multiple `.tlb` files in the parameter list.

Other tools like **Make My Manifest** or **Unattended Make My Manifest** aren't available anymore or don't help me either.

**What is the right way to create a manifest file in this case?**

Comment: This feels more like a winapi/COM question that a Delphi question. If it were me I wouldn't mention Delphi and instead would tag the question winapi com.

Comment: I was thinking about the same. But maybe there is a Delphi specific solution which I've missed so far. I'm still not sure whether it's good or not to mention Delphi here.

Comment: You absolutely need the winapi tag. At the very least remove type-library and regfreecom and add winapi. Personally I'd remove delphi too. There's nothing at all Delphi specific that is going to be relevant, so far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK *RegFree COM* does only support [registration of local instances, via a dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx). There is no way of using it with DCOM, which is something much more complex than local COM.

From my own experiment, DCOM could be a real PITA, especially in terms of registration. IMHO you should either use local COM objects, or switch to another much standard approach, like REST services. You may be able to re-use almost the same interfaces using e.g. [an SOA approach over REST/JSON](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_63) - see especially `sicClientDriven` mode to emulate DCOM objects.

Comment: As I didn't receive any other positive answer within a week I accept this one.

Comment: offtopic, so Arnaud, you blogged ARC in Linux would be nice and easy...

http://kazav.blogspot.ru/2016/03/delphi-arc-arc.html

Comment: @Arioch'The I blogged quite the contrary, AFAIR. For me, forcing ARC on the upcoming Linux platform is a show-stopper.

Comment: BTW have mormot some regression testing suit? I mean kind of how you develop native db adapters?

Comment: mORMot has huge regression tests see [TestSQL3.dpr](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/TestSQL3.dpr) which has very high test coverage, performing  24,049,815 individual tests in its today's version and [some other dedicated to external DB](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/15%20-%20External%20DB%20performance). For a sample of the regression tests output, [see this page](http://pastebin.com/F2aTkkBU).